# drupal 7 metatags by content type

Tags: drupal-7, meta-tags, page-title

I have different custom content types which need completely different tailored for them meta description tags. I have installed the metatags module, however, it gives the possibility to add description meta tags on a site-wide basis and not by content types. The same is with page titles (tho, this can still be solved with the page title module). So i wanted to ask if anyone might know of a good solution to this?

I was also thinking if there is a way to use conditional operator for token, for example, to see if a field is set for a particular node, then add the content of the field to the meta description/keywords.

Answer (score 10):

You can add content type specific meta tags at /admin/config/search/metatags/config/add. There's a drop-down list that  lets you create default metatags by a number of entity attributes, including content type.

I've never integrated tokens with metatag but it appear to be adequately supported.